# Remove line breaks using apps scripts in a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Trying to work out how to remove multiple line breaks from Google Documents (not spreadsheets).

I've tried this and many variations thereof:

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  bodyElement.replaceText("\r\r", '\r');
}
```

Any idea please?
Noob to all of this...

Purpose is to replicate the search and replace in MS Word for ^p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rather "radical" method if your document has only paragraphs with text (images or other elements will be lost). See [doc about element types here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element)

(comments in code)

```
function removeNewLines(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();// get a string
  var textMod=text.replace(/\n/g,'');// replace all \n with ''
  Logger.log(textMod);//optional check in logger
  doc.getBody().clear().appendParagraph(textMod);// empty the doc and apend new texr
  doc.saveAndClose();// save the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing (replace two new lines with a single new line). Ended up with the following as replaceText() doesn't accept \n for some reason.

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  var text_content = text.getText();
  for(var i = 0, offset_i = 0; i < (text_content.length); i++){    
    if((text_content.charCodeAt(i)==10) && (text_content.charCodeAt(i-1)==10)){
      text.deleteText(i-1-offset_i, i-1-offset_i)
      offset_i++;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me to remove doubled new lines in document:

```
function removeDoubleNewLines(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var paragraph;
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length-1; i++) {
    paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    if(paragraph.getText() === '' &&
      paragraph.getNumChildren() === 0) {
      paragraph.removeFromParent();
    }
  }

}
```